# Terraform Error: Incorrect attribute value type for subnet_ids vpc modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax-error, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I am getting the Error: Incorrect attribute value type, when I run terraform plan in version 12.24.

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on .terraform/modules/app/main.tf line 134, in resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db_subnet_group":
 134:   subnet_ids  = var.subnets
    |----------------
    | var.subnets is list of tuple with 1 element

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_ids": incorrect set element type:
string required.
```

Code in tf file:

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db_subnet_group" {
  count = "${var.create_subnet_group ? 1 : 0}"

  name_prefix = "${var.name}-"
  description = "Database subnet group for ${var.name}"
  subnet_ids  = var.subnets
```

The variables.tf file:

```
variable "subnets" {
  description = "Subnets for RDS Instances"
  type        = "list"
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: please put the code where you put the value on var.subnets

Comment: What exactly is `var.subnets`?

Comment: I just added, please check them.

Comment: I mean, what are the actually values you use in `var.subnets`, not its general type.

Comment: @Myra By the way, you have to tag your comments with `@Marcin` for instance. Otherwise people may not get notifications that you've replied.

Comment: A good general tip for debugging situations like this is to use a more accurate type for your variables. If you define your variable as being of type `set(string)`, matching how that `subnet_ids` attribute is defined, then Terraform will report the problem upstream one step in whatever is populating that variable. You can then continue following the references until you find the original expression that was incorrectly producing a list of lists of strings instead of just a list of strings.

Comment: Even when not debugging I'd suggest using precise variable type constraints, because then Terraform can give better feedback when a module caller is using the wrong type.

Comment: @MartinAtkins thank u, I will keep that in mind. Also, can u also help me with this question too if you can: stackoverflow.com/questions/64158451/… thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says that you have `list of tuple with 1 element`, which would mean that the `var.subnets` is something in the form of:

```
variable "subnets" {
  description = "Subnets for RDS Instances"
  type        = "list"
  default = [["subnet-070db0eee8c5f3bb1", "subnet-01e76559b44d06aa3"]]
}
```

Therefore, to use the inner list (i.e. tuple) you have to do:

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db_subnet_group" {
  
  # other attributes not shown

  subnet_ids  = var.subnets[0]
}
```

Comment: can you please help with this question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64158451/terraform-error-in-function-call-when-terraform-plan-runs ... I will appreciate it a lot - @Marcin